# Named Pipes in Scala

Tags: scala, pipe, named-pipes

I would like to use a Named pipe to connect between Scala and Python. However, I am not able to find examples of named pipes in Scala. My Python program generates data and sends the data to either a C++ program or a Scala program. I am able to get the named pipes connection working between Python and C++ but not between Python and Scala. The data producer is the Python file while  either C++ or Scala is the consumer. I
My OS is Ubuntu 14.04.
It would be great if anyone could post examples of named-pipes in scala.
Thanks in advance

Comment: The core Scala library doesn't deal with file IO much - You should probably just search for how to do this in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a Scala-centric approach just to get things started.

```
// first mkfifo /tmp/NP

scala> import scala.io.Source
import scala.io.Source

// this will block until the pipe is written to
scala> val itr = Source.fromFile("/tmp/NP")
itr: scala.io.BufferedSource = non-empty iterator

// after I write "12345 to the end" to the pipe I can work with the iterator

scala> itr.descr
res9: String = file:/tmp/NP

scala> itr.hasNext
res10: Boolean = true

scala> itr.next
res11: Char = 1

scala> itr.next
res12: Char = 2

scala> itr.mkString
res13: String =
"345 to the end
"
```

etc.